# Cannot read property of undefined Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm very new to node.js and I'm having struggle with querying to MySQL DB. This is a very simple web page, all I have to do is read the value from the input and search it on my DB. 
The problem is that var num is still undefined when the web page executes the query. How do I guarantee that I get that value before executing the query?

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var port    =   process.env.PORT || 8001;
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var n_eleitor;
var nome;
var local;
var num_bi;
var num;

//  ---- ROUTES ------
app.get('/', function(req, res) { //homepage
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
    handle_database(req, res);
});

app.get('/result', function(req, res, next) { //results
        res.render('result.ejs', { n_eleitor: n_eleitor, local: local, nome: nome }); 
    });
app.use('/', router);

// ---- CONECTION -----
server.listen(port);

var listener = io.listen(server);
listener.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('client_data', function(data){ //receive data from client
    //console.log(data.letter);
    num_bi = data.letter;
    console.log(num_bi);
    var num = "'"+num_bi+"'";
    console.log(num);
    });
});
// ---- MYSQL ------
var pool = mysql.createPool ({  //pool maitains a cache of database connections -> handles multiple connections
    connectionLimit : 100,
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'soraia',
    database : 'pti2',
});


function handle_database(req, res) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if(err){
            connection.release(); //connection returns to the pool, ready to be used again by someone else.
            return;
        }
        //console.log('ID:' + connection.threadId);

        connection.query("select eleitor.*, freguesia.designacao from freguesia, eleitor where num_bi= ? and freguesia.cod_freg=eleitor.cod_freg",[num], function(err, rows, fields){
           n_eleitor = rows[0].cod_eleitor;
            nome = rows[0].nome;
            local = rows[0].designacao;
            connection.release();
            console.log(num);
            console.log(rows);
        });

    });
}
```

When I run the program I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'cod_eleitor' of undefined" and I think that's because what I said before...
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: can you console you `rows` array

Comment: yes exactly pls console rows and add the structure of rows in question part

Comment: The output is null, rows return empty @clsah

Comment: And I think that it returns empty because the variable in the query is null when the query gets executed